# Change bit depth from Bitmap

Tags: java, android, sqlite, bitmap

So I have an image with a 32 Bit depth, but when I make it into a blob for my SQLite database, and read it out again with the following code it only has a 24 bit depth (the quality is lower, i want it to be the same quality). How do I get it to be 32 Bit depth? :

```
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(camera.this);
            List<Database> contacts = db.getAllContacts();
            for (Database contact : contacts) {
                    BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    bmpFactoryOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
                    //bmpFactoryOptions.inScaled = false;
                    bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight = 240;
                    bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth = 320;
                    // decodes the blob back into a bitmap
                    byte[] blob = contact.getMP();
                    ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(blob);
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                    Bitmap scalen = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 320, 240, false);
```

The Encode source is

```
Bitmap image15 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.wolverineklein);

            // convert bitmap to byte
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            image15.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            byte imageInByte1[] = stream.toByteArray();
```

[image: Left are the properties of the input image (32 bit depth) and right is the output image (24 bit depth)]

Comment: Are you sure you are saving it as 32 bit?

Comment: 1. You have BitmapFactory.Options, but has not used it. 2. Show us the encode source as well.

Comment: I updated my question with the encoding of the image to the database, but what do you mean i'm not using it? I know it doesn't seem to work, but no idea why. And no HaIR i'm not sure i'm saving them correctly as 32 bit.

Comment: How I do use the bitmapFactory options in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as 24 bits depth on Android. A Bitmap can either be, 8 bits (ALPHA 8 format translucency only or null config for paletted formats), 16 bits (565 RGB format without translucency or 4444 RGBA format with translucency) or 32 bits (8888 RGBA format with translucency.)

*Update*: This just means you don't have an alpha channel. Colors are encoded using 24 bits in both cases.

Comment: If you are testing your code on an older version of the platform your JPEG will be decoded in 565 format by default (16 bits). Since you are not passing your BitmapFactory.Options to the decode method, it will remain in 16 bits format. Newer versions of Android always decode in 8888 by default.

Comment: I uploaded the picture, as you can see the left one (input) is 32 bit and the right one is 24 bit (which i get after using the code above)

Comment: This just means you don't have an alpha channel. Colors are encoded using 24 bits in both cases.

Comment: ah oke, and idea how to make it 32 as well? cause the quality of the image is lower as well from the output

Comment: If you don't have translucent pixels there is no reason to make it 32 bits. A 32 bits format is 24 bits for RGB (colors) + 8 bits for alpha (translucency.) If you want to preserve quality encode your image using the PNG format instead of JPEG.

Comment: thank you, this made the quality better (still not as good as the original but hey, i guess that's asking too much :p)